# Go code doesn't compile without an unreachable return statement

Tags: go

Here is the program to find the factorial of a number in Go:

```
func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    }

    return x * (factorial(x - 1))
}
```

The output for this function when called on input 5 is 120. However, if I add an `else` statement I get an error.

```
func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return x * (factorial(x - 1))
    }
}
```

Error : `function ends without a return statement`

I added a `return` at the end :

```
func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return x * (factorial(x - 1))
    }
    fmt.Println("this never executes")
    return 1
}
```

and I get back the expected output of 120.

Why would the second case cause an error? Why in the third case even though the function never reaches the last `return 1`, it computes the correct output?

Comment: It is idiomatic in Go to to use `if cond {return}; return` (not on one line obviously). When you have endless for loops where anything after the loop does not execute, the common idiom is to add `panic("unreachable")`.

Comment: make the last statement a `panic("never reached")`

Comment: Marked as off-topic and voted to close because this "compiler bug" has been fixed and the code in question does not result in compiler error anymore.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a well known problem of the compiler.

There is even an issue logged : http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=65

In the words of one of the authors of the Go language:

> The compilers require either a return or a panic to be lexically last
>   in a function with a result. This rule is easier than requiring full
>   flow control analysis to determine whether a function reaches the end
>   without returning (which is very hard in general), and simpler than
>   rules to enumerate easy cases such as this one. Also, being purely
>   lexical, the error cannot arise spontaneously due to changes in values
>   such as constants used in control structures inside the function.
>
> -rob

From another comment [in golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/u66fQbfbzEo), we can infer it's not going to be "fixed" soon :

> It's not a bug, it's a deliberate design decision.
>
> -rob

Note that other languages like Java have rules allowing this `else`.

---

**March 2013 EDIT -** It just [got changed in Go1.1](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.1) :

> Before Go 1.1, a function that returned a value needed an explicit
>   "return" or call to panic at the end of the function; this was a
>   simple way to make the programmer be explicit about the meaning of the
>   function. But there are many cases where a final "return" is clearly
>   unnecessary, such as a function with only an infinite "for" loop.
>
> In Go 1.1, the rule about final "return" statements is more
>   permissive. It introduces the concept of a terminating statement, a
>   statement that is guaranteed to be the last one a function executes.
>   Examples include "for" loops with no condition and "if-else"
>   statements in which each half ends in a "return". If the final
>   statement of a function can be shown syntactically to be a terminating
>   statement, no final "return" statement is needed.
>
> Note that the rule is purely syntactic: it pays no attention to the
>   values in the code and therefore requires no complex analysis.
>
> Updating: The change is backward-compatible, but existing code with
>   superfluous "return" statements and calls to panic may be simplified
>   manually. Such code can be identified by go vet.

And the issue I mentioned is now closed with status *"Fixed"*.